# Adding title attribute to #type password_confirm

Tags: 7, forms

Is it possible to add a title attribute through a form_alter to element #type 'password_confirm'?

For example, I have a form with the following fields:

- email
- password
- password confirm

To apply a title attribute to the email element is fine...

```
$form['account']['mail']['#attributes']['title'] = 'enter your email address';
```

When I dump the contents of $form in search for the input elements for 'password_confirm', I only get the following:

```
[pass] => Array
                (
                    [#type] => password_confirm
                    [#size] => 25
                    [#description] => We will not spam you or give your email address to third parties.
                    [#required] => 1
                )
```

I'm not seeing 'pass1' and 'pass2' in the array.

Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password confirm element is converted to two fields in a process function ([`form_process_password_confirm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_password_confirm/7)), so adding your own process function to the password element would do the trick.

Per [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/540340) it seems you actually need to overwrite the existing #process array instead of just appending to it, e.g for the user register form password element:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['pass']['#process'] = array(
    'form_process_password_confirm',
    'MYMODULE_password_confirm_process',
    'user_form_process_password_confirm'
  );
}

function MYMODULE_password_confirm_process($element) {
  $element['pass1']['#attributes']['title'] = 'Title';
  $element['pass2']['#attributes']['title'] = 'Title2';
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: "adding your own process function to the password element would do the trick", this I didnt know possible, incredible! Many many thanks Clive.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with drupal 7, I corrected with:

```
function MYMODULE_password_confirm_process($element) {
  $element['pass1']['#title'] = 'Title';
  $element['pass2']['#title'] = 'Title2';
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: This changes the label next to the input, while the OP wanted to change the "title" HTML attribute on the input itself.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly improved version of Clive's answer (based on [a comment from the issue he linked in his answer](https://www.drupal.org/node/540340#comment-6576704)):

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    switch($form_id)
    {
        case 'my_form':
            // Get default process function array:
            $element_info = element_info('password_confirm');
            $process = $element_info['#process'];
            // Add our process function to the array:
            $process[] = 'MYMODULE_process_password_confirm';
            $form['account']['pass']['#process'] = $process;
            break;
    }
}

function MYMODULE_process_password_confirm($element)
{
    $element['pass1']['#attributes']['title'] = 'Title';
    $element['pass2']['#attributes']['title'] = 'Title2';
    return $element;
}
```

The call to the `element_info` function is necessary because the '#process' array can be affected by other modules.