# How do I can change the default description of elements?

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I'm trying to change the default descriptions in different pages like (add users). I tried `devel themer` to find out where there descriptions are came from but it showed nothing. for example look at this picture (add user) :

[image]

how do I can change the texts displayed by red line?

---

**Update**

I tested this code in `template.php`

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if($form_id == "user_register_form"){
    $form['account']['name'] = array(
            '#title' => t('New username'),
            '#description' => t('New description'),
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a job for [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

Comment: Or use [String Overrides module](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) if you don't want to do any coding.

Comment: @FelixEve this module is perfect but there is problem with it, fields which are overridden by this module are not displayed in the users that are not admin and are not able to access overlay. (I have set the permission to every one)

Comment: I've used that module before to override strings shown to anonymous users (on the login page) so I know it can work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your overwriting the whole name array - you only want to update 2 properties:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == "user_register_form"){
    // Here just target the #title attributes - not the whole name array
    $form['account']['name']['#title'] = t('New username');
    // Same here with description.
    $form['account']['name']['#description'] = t('New description');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works perfectly for non-admin user (it is enough for me) but for admin nothing changed. is there any settings or permissions for admin?

Comment: How can an admin user see the register form? If they are admin then they are logged in so can't see the register form at all?

Comment: it is add new user form not the registration

Comment: And I expect the admin page uses a different theme? So your theme functions are not called on admin pages. Solution here is to move this into a custom module as then it will get called whatever theme is active...

Comment: No, admin only uses overlay for this form but others do not.

Comment: But I expect the theme used in the overlay is different to your main theme. If you go to `/admin/appearance` what is your admin theme called?

Comment: No they both use the same theme. I'm sure ;)

Comment: Oh - that's me out of suggestions there I'm afraid... It works for me when I'm logged in as admin. Try putting `dmp($form)` in your `hook_form_alter` function to make sure it's getting called and the values are updated correctly..

Comment: No it didn't get called for admin! and for non-admin users it didn't let the rest of the page to be loaded, it only displayed a white page!!!

Comment: That's very odd. I would try moving this into a custom module anyway to see if that helps.

Comment: I created an interface for specific users that give them the permission to add users. they are not admin, so your solution works for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can find the descriptions at `user.module` under user directory (in modules directory)

you can find those descriptions under `user_account_form` function

Ex, **E-mail address** field description below.

```
$form['account']['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('E-mail address'),
    '#maxlength' => EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#description' => t('A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => (!$register ? $account->mail : ''),
  );
```

But it's better to  Use `hook_form_alter` to achieve it

Comment: But don't change the values in the user.module. Use hook_form_alter in your own module.

Comment: where should be this hook_form_alter? in `template.php` or I should build a module? any difference?

Comment: No difference. Any alter hook can be used in template.php or module file.

Comment: @FelixEve I tested it but it didn't work!

Comment: Add the code your using to your question so we can see whats wrong...

Comment: @FelixEve I update it

Comment: @Drupalist see my new answer

Comment: @FelixEve the `Password` and `Confirm Password` fields are not in the `user.module` and I couldn't find them. where are they?

Comment: @Drupalist [See this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/77827/11306) for updating a `confirm_password` field.